# How can I display the calendar to specific year in Ionic using ion-datetime

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I want to display the calendar in Ionic using ion-datetime in angular framework with default year as current year minus 65 years when I open the datepicker. Only have to show the date format in input field and an icon at the end. On click of icon, have to open the calendar showing the year as current year minus 65 years.
Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: please before asking questions use the documentation provided by platform you are using.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt provide the full info, i had created a sample which will by default set to 65 Years back to the current date as like this[image: this]

See the full code [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-datetime-ynduwb?devtoolsheight=33&file=components/date-picker/date-picker.ts)

Updated Code[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-datetime-ynduwb?file=components/date-display/date-display.ts). If its still not meeting your requireemnt please add your comment what you exactly need.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But my requirement is to display only the format initially and by opening the datepicker, have to show the year as current year minus 65. Only have to update the ngmodel after selecting the date from datepicker

Comment: Hope you can shape it out from here then

Comment: I'm new to ionic. I didn't get the expected output. Could you please help